# Two webservices together in wp7

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-7, soap

i want to use the result of a webservice call in another webservice call which is  just after it...but the 2nd webservice is getting called before the result of 1st webservice.......i am working on wp7 app.....

```
PhoneService.WebServiceSoapClient register = new PhoneService.WebServiceSoapClient();

register.InsertNewCollegeCompleted += register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted;               
register.InsertNewCollegeAsync(newCollegeName);
register.InsertNewCollegeCompleted += register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted;

register.insertdataCompleted += register_insertdataCompleted;            
register.insertdataAsync(Name.Text, email.Text, contact.Text,
        int.Parse(partnerid.Text.Substring(2)), student_no.Text, pass.Text,
        gender, branchid, yearid, collegeid, shirtreqd, accom);
register.insertdataCompleted += register_insertdataCompleted;

void register_insertdataCompleted(object sender, PhoneService.insertdataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("TT ID is" + e.Result);
}

void register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted(object sender, PhoneService.InsertNewCollegeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    collegeid = e.Result;
}
```

Comment: Call the second webservice in `.....Completed` method.

Comment: Its not working, i tried it..

Comment: if you develop using VS2012, there is option to use [async/await](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx?PageIndex=2) as clean solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use Asynccalls , you basically wanted to use register first and then its response in your login Api..
I have done this by making Asynchronous calls awaitable, you can look at the link. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8 
And also this will too help:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/518856/Task-Parallel-Library-and-async-await-Functionalit

Comment: sir can u plz give me a sample about the conversion of method....because it is giving me the error cannot await void..

Comment: my webmethod is....                              [WebMethod]
    public string details()
    {
        Connect detail;
        string sql = "SELECT CollegeName  FROM colleges";
        string[] s = { "@ttid"};
        Connect.ConnectTT();
        detail = new Connect(sql);
        return detail.ds.GetXml();
        
}

Comment: You should read the tutorial carefully you are making an initial mistake i.e. you have to make the function ASYNC like your fucntion is   
public async Task details()  
and if you want to return something then 
public async Task<string> details()

Comment: And you have to make    
register.insertdataAsync(Name.Text, email.Text, contact.Text,
        int.Parse(partnerid.Text.Substring(2)), student_no.Text, pass.Text,
        gender, branchid, yearid, collegeid, shirtreqd, accom);
awaitable like use await in starting of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the second web service call in Completed method of first service call

In your case, call the register.insertdataAsync method in register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted as

```
{
....
....
            PhoneService.WebServiceSoapClient register =
     new PhoneService.WebServiceSoapClient();

            register.InsertNewCollegeCompleted += register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted;               
            register.InsertNewCollegeAsync(newCollegeName); 
....
....
}



    void register_InsertNewCollegeCompleted(object sender, PhoneService.InsertNewCollegeCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            collegeid = e.Result;
    register.insertdataCompleted += register_insertdataCompleted;            
        register.insertdataAsync(Name.Text, email.Text, contact.Text,
                int.Parse(partnerid.Text.Substring(2)), student_no.Text, pass.Text,
                gender, branchid, yearid, collegeid, shirtreqd, accom);
        }

    void register_insertdataCompleted(object sender, PhoneService.insertdataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TT ID is" + e.Result);
    }
```